# Loop thru child DIVs and Get IDs

Tags: jquery

I have my HTML setup as follows (IDs are madeup for sake of example):

```
<div id="selected-area">
    <div id="01" class="folder-ready"> </div>
    <div id="02" class="folder-ready"> </div>
    <div id="03" class="folder-ready"> </div>
    <div id="04" class="folder-ready"> </div>
    <div id="05" class="folder-ready"> </div>
</div>
```

What is the simplest method to loop through all child DIVs of `selected-area` and put each of their IDs into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:-

```
$('#selected-area div').each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});​​​​​
```

With Array:

```
var tempArray = new Array();
$('#selected-area div').each(function() {
    tempArray.push(this.id);
});
alert(tempArray);
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/RkFaU/1/)**

### UPDATE:

Another way of representation:-

```
var tempArray = $('#selected-area div').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).toArray();
alert(tempArray);
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/RkFaU/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = new Array();

$('div','#selected-area').each(function(){
    array.push($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var idArray = $('#selected-area > div').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```